# how to copy a single cell to another sheet and pasting to 18 cells and loop until blanks on source sheet

Tags: vba, excel

hiya all thanks in advance for any help

my goal is to transfer all the data from a discount grid and converting it to a list format

i have the grid as the source sheet and i am creating a new sheet ready for import to a new system which needs it laying out in a list format
name(A)-type(B)-(C)-discount(D) 
(column c must be blank)

1 i need to take the company name and copy it 17 more times (for each product type)

2 i then take the product types from the top and transpose into next column

3 i then miss out 1 column then copy and transpose in the discount values in the next column

this then needs to be repeated until it finds a blank on the source page

i have constructed a basic macro but it means ill have to redo for each customer which currently stands at 939 customers (nightmare) is there a set of commands i can put into my macro to achive this ?

here is a copy of my current code

```
    Workbooks.Add
    ChDir "F:\darren t"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="F:\darren t\Ready Discount Grid.xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Windows("Tools for ball.xlsm").Activate
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="F:\darren t\DISCOUNTS GRID M2M.xlsx"
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearFormats
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("B2:S936").Select
    Range("S936").Activate
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Range("A2").Select

'Create grid names

    Windows("Ready Discount Grid.xlsx").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Customer Account Code"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Blind Type Code"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Option Stock Code"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Discount %"
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

' paste names (repeat 938 times)

    Windows("DISCOUNTS GRID M2M.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Ready Discount Grid.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A19"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A2:A19").Select

    Windows("DISCOUNTS GRID M2M.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Ready Discount Grid.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A20").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A20:A37"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A20:A37").Select

    Windows("DISCOUNTS GRID M2M.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Ready Discount Grid.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A38").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A38:A57"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A38:A57").Select

    Windows("DISCOUNTS GRID M2M.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Ready Discount Grid.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A58").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A58:A73"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A58:A73").Select

    Windows("DISCOUNTS GRID M2M.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Ready Discount Grid.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A74").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A74:A91"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A74:A91").Select

    Windows("DISCOUNTS GRID M2M.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Ready Discount Grid.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A92").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A92:A109"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A92:A109").Select

    Windows("DISCOUNTS GRID M2M.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Ready Discount Grid.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A110").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A110:A127"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A110:A127").Select

    Windows("DISCOUNTS GRID M2M.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A9").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Ready Discount Grid.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A128").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A128:a145"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A128:A145").Select

' paste types (repeat 938 times)

    Windows("DISCOUNTS GRID M2M.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B1:W1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Ready Discount Grid.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Windows("DISCOUNTS GRID M2M.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B1:W1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Ready Discount Grid.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B20").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Windows("DISCOUNTS GRID M2M.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B1:W1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Ready Discount Grid.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B38").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'paste discount values (repeat 938 times)

    Windows("DISCOUNTS GRID M2M.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B2:S2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Ready Discount Grid.xlsx").Activate
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

        Windows("DISCOUNTS GRID M2M.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B3:S3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Ready Discount Grid.xlsx").Activate
    Range("D20").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

    Windows("DISCOUNTS GRID M2M.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B4:S4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Ready Discount Grid.xlsx").Activate
    Range("D38").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

'Put rest of the data below here


End Sub
```

there must be a much more efficent way to do this

any help would be amazing

Comment: too long didnt even read... please post a **small** snippet of your code that doesnt work with a description.

Comment: Use a loop structure. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692812(v=office.15).aspx) for a list of VBA statements which include `For Each ... Next` and `For ... Next` statements.  Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) to avoid using "Activate" and "Select" methods in VBA programming.

Comment: not really fair to minus 1 me based on trying to be informative rather than vague but i appreciate the honesty

Comment: thank you for both answers im now well on my way to being more efficient :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help

```
Do while activecell.value <> ""
   'Code that must repeat

   Activecell.Offset(1,0).Active 'Moves the active cell
Loop
```

> activecell.value

Evaluates the activecell value, which one in the case that it's empty will stop